# How to plot a quarter of circle using Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot a quarter of circle using `x` as abscissa while `y` as ordinate by taking advantage of the `Plot` function of Mathematica when `a` is in the range of `[0,Pi/2]` ?

```
x=2*Sin[a];
y=2*Cos[a];
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to use `ParametricPlot`?

Comment: @xzczd, I am sorry for my poor experience in using mathematica and I haven't used `ParametricPlot` till now. But in fact, it really works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot.html), not `Plot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{2*Sin[a], 2*Cos[a]}, {a, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You should leave some easy ones for the newer/intermediate users, y'know...

Comment: @rm-rf  I doubt SunnySky is unhappy about getting an answer *sooner* rather than having to wait until later.

Comment: It is kinda discouraging to see you answer all the low hanging fruits, is all I'm saying. These posts allow new and intermediate users to feel like they're contributing something to the site and it's important to realize that we also need to constantly build a pool of users who are motivated to answer questions. This is not a race to see who can answer all the low hanging questions... FYI, I prowl the site way more often and compulsively than you do and have been doing so since January; I leave most of the low hanging ones and only answer some when I've gone a stretch without much rep gain.

Comment: @rm-rf I'd like to hear about this "problem" from some of the "new and intermediate users" I'm supposedly discouraging rather than one of the top dogs (or frogs).  It's not as though I am responding to the *majority* of questions as I once did on SO; I'm busier now and the site is much busier.  I still see the site as being *primarily* about getting help, not gaining "points," and I feel that delaying or omitting answers works against this goal.

Comment: @rm-rf Also, I don't doubt that you could answer a lot more questions than you do but I don't know if your reserve is actually *helping* anyone (besides me perhaps as it is kinda fun being at the top of the score board).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution from graphics primitive [**Circle**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Circle.html):

```
Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/2}]]
```

[image]

I am not sure what the final goal of your question is, but maybe this will help - this is how to use graphics primitives inside `Plot`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/2}]},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

You can provide a lot of options to `Circle`, including making it [**elliptic**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0deiu6-2sv5q). Here is basic options for circular arc:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   {CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.05], Blue, 
    Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {a, a + s}]},
   {Thick, Circle[]}}]
 , {{a, 0, "position"}, 0, 2 Pi}
 , {{s, Pi/2, "angle"}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting but I don't think it answers the question asked.  (+1/-1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard oh, forgot to read below the title... :) keep/delete?

Comment: Keep; someone's bound to stumble onto this question when looking for the functionality you show, so I deem it helpful.  I just can't make up my mind on the vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I don't see how this wouldn't answer OP's question. Granted Vitaliy doesn't use `Plot`, but `ParametricPlot` isn't `Plot` either. And with `Graphic` and `Circle` the result is there! :-)

Comment: @stevenvh the OP specifically asks to plot (lower case) this from given equations for `x` and `y` over a specific interval.  None of that is in this answer.  Presumably the OP didn't know about `ParametricPlot` and just assumed that the functionality was somewhere in `Plot`.